# The constructor ClassMethod(String, double, int) is undefined

Tags: java

In my main class I have the following code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClasePrincipal {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Alumno;
        String nombre = "";
        double promedio = 0;
        int id = 0;
        int user=0;
        ClassMethod m [] = new ClassMethod [3];
        ClassMethod obj1 = new ClassMethod();

        while (user!=0)
        System.out.println("NOMINA DE ALUMNOS CURSO PEF2501");
        System.out.println("__________________________________");
        System.out.println("1. Imprimir Nomina De Alumnos");
        System.out.println("2. Matricular Alumno");
        System.out.println("3. Remover Alumno");
        System.out.println("4. Comprobar Matricula Alumno");
        System.out.println("__________________________________");
        System.out.println("Elija Una Opcion");
        user=leer.nextInt ();

        if (user==2){
            ClassMethod.matricular();

        }
          m [0] = new ClassMethod(nombre,promedio,id);
          System.out.println(m[0]);


    }  
}
```

In ClassMethod I have the following code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClassMethod {

    static Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static  String nombre;
    public static double promedio;
    public static int id;
    public static int cm=-1;


    public ClassMethod (){
        nombre = "";
        promedio = 0;
        id = 0;
    }


    public ClassMethod (String n,int i,double p){
         nombre=n;
         id=i;
         promedio=p;

    }

    public static void matricular(){
        cm++;
        id=cm++;
        System.out.println("Ingrese El Nombre Del Alumno");
        nombre=leer.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese El Promedio Del Alumno");
        promedio=leer.nextDouble();

    }

    public void setId(int id){
          this.id = id;
         }

     public int getId(){
          return id;
         }

     public void setNombre(String nombre){
          this.nombre= nombre;
         }

     public String getNombre(){
          return nombre;
         }

     public void setPromedio (double promedio){
         this.promedio=promedio;
     }

     public double getPromedio (){
         return promedio;
     }
}
```

Eclipse give me this error:

The constructor ClassMethod(String, double, int) is undefined

Please Help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the order wrong, this

```
m [0] = new ClassMethod(nombre,promedio,id);
```

should be

```
m [0] = new ClassMethod(nombre,id, promedio);
```

because your constructor takes `String`, `int`, `double`. Also, your `while` loop appears to be missing braces (so it only includes the immediately following line).

Comment: I was just about to answer that. Congrats! You win a +1